# Why is the returned 'reason' from a rejected jQuery AJAX call thenable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I recently hit a subtle bug in my code related to jQuery AJAX calls and promises.  In short what the code was doing was equivalent to:

```
Promise
    .resolve($.ajax(...))
    .catch(function(err){return err})
    .then(function(response){//do something with response}
```

The reasons for doing this are unimportant right now, and of course there were lots of other parts the promise chain not listed above which are not relevent to the problem.  What I wanted to happen was the rejection reason from the AJAX call to end up on the resolved path, however it was re-rejecting each time.

I eventually found that the response returned from a rejected jQuery AJAX call has a then method which will reject with itself as the reason.  To be clear:

```
Promise.resolve($.ajax(...)) //an ajax call which will reject
    .catch(function(err){
        err.then(null,function(err2){
            if (err===err2) console.log("AJAX error rejects with itself as a reason!");
        });
    });
```

will log the message given on the console.

My question is simply why has this been done?  Is there a good reason for a returned reason for a rejected promise to itself be thenable?  Further is there are good reason as well that this thenable should reject with itself as a reason?

---

To avoid confusion, below is the second code block, re-written to use the same chained style as the first block and an external variable to store the returned error.

```
var reason;
Promise
    .resolve($.ajax(...))
    .catch(function(err){
        reason=err;
        return err
    })
    .then(function(response){//will not be called if the ajax rejects}
    .catch(function(err){
        if (err===reason) console.log("AJAX error rejects with itself as a reason!");
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with promises, cause Promise returns resolve and reject in itsef;

when you do this

```
Promise.resolve($.ajax(...)) //an ajax call which will reject
.catch(function(err){
    err.catch(function(err2){
        if (err===err2) console.log("AJAX error rejects with itself as a reason!");
    });
});
```

you resolves any result of jquery ajax call, and it always will work fine and you nr

Comment: First of all I made a mistake in the second code block above and should have used `.then(null, ...)` rather than `.catch(...)`.  Second I have resolved the returned object within the catch function so the `err` object is still available within the nested catch block so I can compare them.  Of course I can return the error value and have it resolve as a promise and then reject, but then `err` would not be available unless I stored it in an external closure.